# Homepage loads, no other pages do

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5.3, ubuntu-16.04

I have my laravel project on my nginx ubuntu webserver.

I can see the homepage, but all of the other pages fail.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I suspect it's something to do with this line in the sites available file:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Could anyone post their own sites available file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args;
}
```

Full config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /path/to/your/laravel/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name your_domain.com;
    charset utf-8;

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied off;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/javascript application/json application/xml application/xml+rss;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/your_error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|svg|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {                expires 1M;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            expires 7d;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks, what does that actually do? Also I don't suppose you could paste your sites available file, I would like to check Ive got this set up correct. Thanks

Comment: @panthro Added the full config. Replaced some info like domainname and install path